# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL after code passes jslint "use strict" check okay

Tags: javascript, jquery, use-strict

I have the following code from my team mate

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*jslint vars: true */
/*global $, jQuery*/
/*global dialog*/

function accessControls() {
    "use strict";

    $('#loginLink, #registerLink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).data("disabled") === "false") {
            $("a.accessLink").data("disabled", "true");
            dialog(this);
        }
    });

}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<a  class="button accessLink"
            id="loginLink"
            href="#"
            data-action="Login"
            data-dialog="access"
            data-disabled="false"
            data-entity="n/a"
            data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Login"
            title="Login">Login</a>
```

It's giving me a message in the Chrome browser that says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.  The message comes right after the last semicolon of the code above. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong.

Note that when I comment out the line dialog it works. So is this something to do with the "this" ?

Comment: You need to post the code that wrapped this.

Comment: what is dialog() here.. Is it Dialog box from jQuery UI

Comment: I posted the wrapper code. This is all there is. Dialog is our group's javascript function to create modal boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using equality operator(===) for Boolean variable then you need not to pass false as string

```
if($(this).data("disabled") === "false"){
// some code
}
```

need to be changed in

```
if($(this).data("disabled") === false) {
// some code 
}
```

anyways if you can post code what is wrapping it that would be better understanding.

and on which jQuery object you are calling dialog()?

Comment: Just posted everything. Note that I get no error if I comment out the dialog line or if I set the parameter to ().